# Countable union of compatible continuous functions is continuous.

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f_n\colon [n,n+1]\to \Bbb R $ be a sequence, $n\in\mathbb Z$, such that all $f_n$ are continuous function  and $f_n(n+1)=f_{n+1}(n+1).$ Define $f$ as $$f=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z} f_n,$$

> - Is  $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ continuous function ?

Indeed, it is clear $f$ is a function since it has the same value in the common points. To see $f$ is continuous, let $U$ be an open of $\Bbb R$, it is enought to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Note that $$f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z} f_n^{-1}(U),$$ is open since each $f_n$ is continuous and a countable union (even arbitbrary still open)  of open sets are open. Am I missing something ?.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Mark, I edited my question

Comment: I'd be more careful with "endpoints". Indeed, for example $f_n:[n,n+1] \to \mathbb R$ given by $f_n(x) = x$ are continuous (with respect to euclidean topology on subspace (in domain) and euclidean topology in co-domain). But for $U=(0,3)$ you have $f_1^{-1}[U] = [1,2]$, which is indeed open in $[1,2]$ (domain of $f_1$) but not in $\mathbb R$. It is important that $f_2(2)=2$ so that $f_2^{-1}[U] \ni \{2\}$ and it "glues" well together, but something should be written more carefully, especially while u're learning.

Comment: @Cornman, I edited my question

Comment: @DominikKutek, Thank you. feel free to edit my answer to be more accurate

Comment: What I meant, the problem lies in the very last part. It isn't true that $f_n^{-1}[U]$ is open in $\mathbb R$, but only in $[n,n+1]$ (that is, subspace topology)

Comment: @DominikKutek, but about $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R$. right?

Comment: You want to prove it

Comment: @DominikKutek, I thought it is obvious but it needs to be checked